# Can you divide long sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, tense, phrase-usage

Can you divide long sentences like this?

"I like apple that the red one" (long) -> I like apple. and the apple is red. (short, easy)

The original sentence is this:

> 1. Researchers go further, developing a “meta theory” of culture  as an individual property  composed  by  tiles of demographic, geographic, and associative  differences.
> 2. Different tiles of the mosaic can be activated by situational cues, serving either to connect culturally dissimilar team members across common tiles or to fracture them along faultlines.

Comment: The first sentence is a mess, please correct it!

Comment: Should it be: "I like apple**s like** the red one"?

Answer (score 2):

First, your example with apples is not grammatical.  "I like apple that the red one" is so ungrammatical that it is hard to see what you mean. And your turning it into two sentences isn't right.  "I like apple" should be "I like apples". But then the second part is unclear.

As to the two sentences at the end, it is certainly possible to divide them, but I am not sure any clarity is gained. For example

> researcher go further, developing a “meta theory” of culture as an
>   individual property composed by tiles of demographic, geographic, and
>   associative differences.

could be turned into

> researchers go further, developing a “meta theory” of culture. This
>   meta theory sees culture as an individual property composed by tiles
>   of demographic, geographic, and associative differences.